# deleting specific dictionary items in python (based on key format)

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, dictionary

I have a python dictionary consisting of key value pairs. What I want to do is delete items who’s keys are a certain format.
In my case format of the keys I want to delete are: Letter, number, number.
Example: A12, A56, A32

So in the below case I want to delete all the items that consist of an Axx (where the x’s are numbers).

```
{'A34': 83, 'B32': 70, 'A44': 66, A12: 47, 'B90': 71}
```

I know that the format can be targeted using regex.
For example the following code will count the number of keys that have the Axx format (where x’s are numbers)

```
print(sum(1 for k in d.keys() if re.match('^A\\d{2}$', k)))
```

But how can I change this around so that it can delete the item of the dictionary whos key Is of the Axx format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dictionary comprehension:

```py
dct = {'A34': 83, 'B32': 70, 'A44': 66, 'A12': 47, 'B90': 71}
dct = {k:v for k,v in dct.items() if not re.fullmatch(r'A\d{2}', k) }
```

The `if not re.fullmatch(r'A\d{2}', k)` condition filters out (removes) any items with key that fully matches `A<two digits>` pattern (note that `re.fullmatch` requires a full string match hence no need for anchors).

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in dictionary:
    if condition(key):
        del dictionary[key]
```

```
# Adapted to your code
temp = dictionary.copy()
for k in dictionary:
    if re.fullmatch(r'A\d{2}', k):
        del temp[k]
dictionary = temp
```

Comment: One shouldn't remove an item in a `for` loop.

Comment: @j1-lee The for loop is using a generator, meaning it will not affect the del, especially the key of a dictionary

Comment: Then why do I see `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`?

Comment: @j1-lee Np. Changes made

Comment: Must be in-place modification... hmm

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the matches with `pop` or `del`. To avoid modifying the dictionary while iterating over it you can iterate over the dictionary keys

```
d = {'A34': 83, 'B32': 70, 'A44': 66, 'A12': 47, 'B90': 71}
for k in list(d.keys()):
    if re.match('^A\\d{2}$', k):
        d.pop(k) # del d[k]
print(d) # {'B32': 70, 'B90': 71}
```